# Parse.com stability

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

Would increasing the transaction bandwidth of my parse.com account help reduce errors, although the errors I am seeing are not due to over usage of transactions.

Comment: Could you please remove the rant parts of this post, and instead write a clear problem statement?

Comment: is the question now clearer?

Comment: It is certainly easier to read. ;) However, I still don't think that this is something [which can be discussed here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). What kind of answer do you expect? Do you think that someone hear can tell you about the roadmap of parse.com? Even if there are parse.com employees here, it's very unlikely that they will comment on internal issues on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I'll further reduce my comment to get at the core of the question.

Comment: It is hard to answer the question without knowing exactly what errors you are getting? I used parse for over a year in semi heavy use cases with no problems other then the occasional downtime. If your errors are not related to the over use of transactions as you say then it should make zero difference. I am guessing there is a problem in your cloud code.

Comment: The problem in the cloud code would then always produce this error.  , or at least more often. We looked into it and it coincided with the elevated error rate event on status.parse.com

Comment: What's the error log?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked you are not exceeding any of the many limits Parse has?
Here is a (not-sure-how-updated) list that may help

http://profi.co/all-the-limits-of-parse/

Some of the ones listed in there:

- 160 API requests per minute for ENTIRE app (not one instance!) (changed to 30+ req/s but it costs quite a lot
- limited number of COUNT operations (differs every time, but surely under 160)
- any function can not take longer than 3 seconds
- if that function is in a cloud that time can last 7 seconds
- ...